# Difference between apply and funcall

Tags: apply, funcall

`(describe-function apply)` says:

```
apply is a built-in function in ‘src/eval.c’.                                                                                                                                                                      

(apply FUNCTION &rest ARGUMENTS)                                                                                                                                                                                   

Call FUNCTION with our remaining args, using our last arg as list of 
args.                                                                                                                                         
Then return the value FUNCTION returns.                                                                                                                                                                            
Thus, (apply '+ 1 2 '(3 4)) returns 10.
```

`(describe-function funcall)` says:

```
funcall is a built-in function in ‘src/eval.c’.                                                                                                                                                                    

(funcall FUNCTION &rest ARGUMENTS)     

Call first argument as a function, passing remaining arguments to it.
Return the value that function returns.
Thus, (funcall 'cons 'x 'y) returns (x . y).
```

What is the difference between these two function?

Comment: `(apply #'+ 1 2 '(3 4))` is the same as `(funcall #'+ 1 2 3 4)`. In other words, `(funcall FN X Y Z)` is the same as `(apply FN (list X Y Z))`.

Comment: "using our last arg as list of args" is the key phrase in the quoted documentation.  It means you can say things like `(apply #'FUNC ARGS)` where ARGS is an arbitrary list which has likely been *supplied or generated by other code*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `apply` when you don't know what the individual arguments are, or how many there are. You can use `funcall` (or `apply`) when you do know that.

For example, suppose your *list of args* to apply the function to is the value of variable `foo`. Then you would use `(apply 'some-fun foo)`.

If you know that you're going to apply the function to args `3`, `toto`, and `4`, in that order, then you can use `(apply 'some-fun (list 3 'toto 4))` or `(funcall 'some-fun 3 'toto 4)`.